# iOS detect Airplay during app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

We are building an iOS app where users can watch videos under a subscription model.

We don't want users to Airplay the videos to any other device.

The video is being played inside a UIWebView.

I checked various online resources:

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617973-mediaplaybackallowsairplay?language=objc
2. https://github.com/MobileVet/AirPlayDetector

The above options have not worked.

Also, i tried this code but it always return 1.

```
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] < 2)) {
//streaming
}
else {
//mirroring
}
```

I have tried this code as well:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveAirPlayNotification:) name: UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
```

This notification system works only when i launch the App and then turn on Airplay. If i turn on Airplay and then launch the App, then nothing is detected.

I need to detect if mirroring is on when the app launches. I have seen other apps do this so i am sure this is possible.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
- (BOOL)isAirplayOn
{
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* outputPort in currentRoute.outputs){
        if ([outputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Thanks for the help. This code is working!! :)

Comment: Hi Ganesh. In the latest iOS 11, screen recording feature is there. I can detect it when i start recording after opening the app using: UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification. But is there any way to detect it if i start the recording first and then open the app (similar to the code you had share above)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217459/how-to-understand-if-device-screen-is-being-recorded-in-ios-11/46218452#46218452

Comment: @GaneshBavaskar are you able to detect mirroring with this or Airplay?